# Using Times Roman (mathptmx package) in the text but keeping default LaTeX font for math mode

Tags: fonts, times, mathptmx

I would like to use Times Roman font for the main text, but keeping the standart LaTeX font for math mode. I tried the **mathptmx** package but it changes both main text and math mode font. I know which the **times** package produces the desired result, but it is now obsolete. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The shapes of the standard math fonts don't blend at all with Times New Roman.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want this (questionable) combination using the package times is ok (but check if the sans serif and typewriter is too your liking).

You can also simply add `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` to your preamble if you only want to change the roman font.

Comment: It worked well!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{tgheros}%% TeX Gyre Sans Serif
\usepackage{tgtermes}%%           TeX Gyre Times
\begin{document}

foo \textsf{bar} \textbf{baz}

\[ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x = 1 \]

\end{document}
```